# Deserialize float number into a 'float' type instead of default 'double' in Json.NET

Tags: c#, floating-point, json.net

Actually, the question is in the title already. Providing more details, I have to specify that I know about a custom converters and would like to avoid this scenario. I hope may be there is a *setting* which I can use to tune serializer for using `float` instead of `double` by default.

For example, we can use `FloatParseHandling.Decimal` for same purpose to use `decimal` instead, but not for `float`.

The model, which I expect to deserialize into:

```
public class Figure
{
    public float SideA { get; set; }
    public float SideB { get; set; }
    public float SideC { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What are you deserializing *into*? Normally, I would expect to see a class-based model that you're deserializing into; just make the relevant property a `float` instead of a `double`?

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks for paying attention, I've edited the Q. For this definition I'm getting `double` in deserialized value and the model doesn't match

Comment: You you don't. There is no way in which a float can hold a double

Comment: @erikkallen I didn't get you clearly, could you explain what you meant?

Comment: Your model has a property of type `float`. This means that the value stored in it is of type `float`.

Comment: @erikkallen I'm asking about possibility to use `float` type as default while deserializing into the model from json object, so how is your comment relate? sorry, I can't understand

Comment: @anatol I think what they mean is: please show minimal code, like in Vabka's answer, that shows the problem you're seeing - because it *should* "just work"

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks you all, I think it's really another one issue there as it actually *should* work as is

Comment: @anatol that's why it is especially useful to show code that demonstrates the problem; this works just fine with your `Figure` class, for example: `var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Figure>(@"{ ""sidea"": 123.456 }");` and `System.Console.WriteLine(obj.SideA);` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problems when deserializing. Show your code

```cs
    #r "nuget:Newtonsoft.Json/13.0.1"
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

    var json = "{ \"num\": 1.5 }";

    var jAnon = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json , new { num = 0.0f }); // Use anonymous type
    var jClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Json>(json); // use class
    var jObj = JObject.Parse(json);

    var value = jObj.GetValue("num");
    value.Value<float>(); // use JObject

    class Json {
      public float Num {get;set;}
    }
```